# import excel data in Jupyter notebook faced with problem

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I want to import excel data in jupyter notebook,in the python 3.7, but I got the following errors, can anyone explain to me the solution of the problem awaiting for your kind response.
[image]

Comment: please copy paste the **complete** error message you are getting. don't post part of it, don't post screenshots

Comment: Please make sure you specify the complete path of the xlsx file in ```pd.read_excel()```

Comment: it says "FileNotFoundError", meaning specified path to the file is probably wrong. Is 'com.xlsx' in the same directory and the juniper notebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your path is correct for the excel file. Also, pay attention to slash '/' It is NOT '\'.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

my_path = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/2nd Semester Research Topic'
df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(my_path,'com.xlsx'))
```

Comment: I have run it, but i didn't get the result . just no errors show, then what should to do ?

Comment: Add `print(df)`. So that's it. Your excel file data is in the variable `df` now. Could you please mark the answer as the correct answer if it works?